# Finding the remainder

Tags: number-theory

What is the general form of the remainder when $N$ divides ${1^{N-1}}$$+$$2^{N-1}$$+$$3^{N-1}$$+...+$${(N-1)}^{(N-1)}$?

The fermat's little theorem is applicable only $N$ being prime but we've been facing trouble with this bugger. Some insights or the complete solution.

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A204187. They give no general form, which pretty strongly suggests that there is none. Pretty often the sum is 0 (http://oeis.org/A191677) or $N/2$.

Comment: Giuga's Conjecture is that if the remainder is $N-1$ then $N$ is prime (the converse is true by Fermat). The conjecture is unsolved, so your general question is hopeless. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh–Giuga_conjecture

Comment: OK, jyotishraj?

Comment: Where can I get some more information about this conjecture.

Comment: If you mean Giuga's conjecture, I gave a link in a comment (or you could just type "Giuga's conjecture" into the internet, and see what comes back at you). And if you want to be certain I see a comment addressed to me, you have to put @Gerry into it.